# Debug Laravel Queues

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, horizon

I am new to laravel queues but this situation has occurred to me and I have no clue to fix . I am processing a queue using dispatch method and wanted to print an array in a service called in job class. I have tried print_r , dd with exit but nothing is working.

PS: I am using redis and debugging the queues in horizon. I am also checking  logs for any exception but its not showing print_r result there.

Please suggest if there is a way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dd() and print_r won't work.

> wanted to print an array in a service called in job class

You should use [Log](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging#writing-log-messages) what you want to debug and check last logs in `storage/logs` folder. Often it is `laravel.log` file. You can any following method.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

Log::debug($message);
```

Comment: Yes I guess this is an only way :( . Thanks

Comment: Yes. You cannot use dd() and print_r(), because jobs are processed in background

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `Cache` facade with method `put()`. Next, you can get this with `Cache::get($cacheKey);`. Here I can pass any data type: **Collections**, **arrays**, **integer**, **string**, etc. And that's its advantage